# External Button to open/close Accordion

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I need help to open or close accordion with extra buttons.

Here is example of the accordion with buttons:

```js
$(function() {
    $( "#tab1" ).accordion({
        collapsible: true, active: false, heightStyle: "content"
    });
    $( "#tab2" ).accordion({
        collapsible: true, active: false, heightStyle: "content"
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">

<div id="tab1">
    <h3>Tab 1</h3>
    <div>1234567890 Text</div>
</div>
<div id="tab2">   
    <h3>Tab 2</h3>
    <div>1234567890 Text 2</div>
</div>
<button><span>Open/Close Tab1</span></button>
<button><span>Open/Close Tab2</span></button>
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can trigger the click event manually:

```js
$(function() {
    $( "#tab1" ).accordion({
        collapsible: true, active: false, heightStyle: "content"
    });
    $( "#tab2" ).accordion({
        collapsible: true, active: false, heightStyle: "content"
    });

    $('button').first().click(function(){
        $('h3').first().click();
    });
    $('button').last().click(function(){
        $('h3').last().click();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">

<div id="tab1">
    <h3>Tab 1</h3>
    <div>1234567890 Text</div>
</div>
<div id="tab2">   
    <h3>Tab 2</h3>
    <div>1234567890 Text 2</div>
</div>
<button><span>Open/Close Tab1</span></button>
<button><span>Open/Close Tab2</span></button>
```

Comment: Answer I was working on adivsed adding ids to the buttons and using something like `$('#tab2Btn').on('click', function(){
      $('#tab2 h3').click();
    })` as the handler, might be a little more extensible.  This works too though.

Comment: @IrkenInvader Good, it's strange that they have no method like collapse()/expand() for controlling this via code...

Answer (score 0):

Use "active" from the accordion's API: http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/#option-active.

```js
$(function() {
    $( "#tab1" ).accordion({
        collapsible: true, active: false, heightStyle: "content"
    });
    $( "#tab2" ).accordion({
        collapsible: true, active: false, heightStyle: "content"
    });
    $('.toggle-tab').on('click', function(){
      var $accordion = $('#tab' + $(this).data('tab'));
      var state = $accordion.accordion('option', 'active');
      $accordion.accordion('option', {active: state === 0 ? false : 0 });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">

<div id="tab1">
    <h3>Tab 1</h3>
    <div>1234567890 Text</div>
</div>
<div id="tab2">   
    <h3>Tab 2</h3>
    <div>1234567890 Text 2</div>
</div>
<button class="toggle-tab" data-tab="1"><span>Open/Close Tab1</span></button>
<button class="toggle-tab" data-tab="2"><span>Open/Close Tab2</span></button>
```